# How can I pass GET parameters and still use # to jump to a part of my page?

Tags: html, http, navigation, get

So I'm developping a mobile web application and at some point, I have the following:

```
<a href="index.php?key=blabla#detailsDepense">
```

It almost does what's intended, it navigates to index.php and jumps to the detailsDepense section.  Unfortunately, it just drops the 'key' GET parameter from the url and make it inaccessible from php.

How can I pass GET parameters while still using the hash (#) in my URL?

Comment: Are you able to access to the key parameter if you drop the # and the rest?

Comment: The code given should provide the results you request and not the results you describe getting. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Any particular platform and framework in use? The `a` tag you provided should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format a 'pseudo-hash' into your querystring as a GET variable...

```
<a href="index.php?key=blabla&hash=etailsDepense">
```

Then, in your page, pass that variable to location.hash using PHP/JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if ($_GET['hash']) { ?>
        location.hash = <?php echo "'".$_GET['hash']."';";
    } ?>
</script>
```

Simple as that!